# How to tell Node.JS to use modules from global by default?

Tags: node.js, npm

Is there any chance to tell Node.Js to also look in the global modules folder by default, without changing sources?

I am trying to avoid that my project folders (up to a hundred packages) gets messed with thousands of sub-folders (also, it slows most IDEs into their knees too). I am aware about the npm link trick but it doesn't work on all platforms or its causing other problems. Also, npm/npm3 is sometimes so slow that i have to wait an entire day that my project is ready for actually working on it (i have a top speed computer and broadband).

known solutions:

- changing NODE_PATH environment is out for some other reasons, shell .rc changes are little bad too.
- changing core files is easy but requires also patches in many other places (when using nodejs. as dependency for instance )
- patching node.js's require function as in other versions like require-js which supports require({cache:{}}) or require({config:{}})

Comment: You could take advantage of [`NODE_PATH` environment variable](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders).

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny, thanks. That just opens a whole can of other worms :-)

Comment: Have you checked out these? http://mixu.net/npm_lazy/ or https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-cache

Comment: And also this one: https://lincolnloop.com/blog/speeding-npm-installs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I went with https://github.com/h2non/requireg. It doesn't need any kiddie hacks like npm link or special environment variables and works fantastic. It comes with a globalize function which makes subsequent require calls also looking in the global folders.